# ConTeXt : equivalent to LaTeX esvect

Tags: context, vector

When using LaTeX, I used the esvect package, which has the following interesting features :

- very well lengthed vector arrows
- a lot of arrow versions
- a particular attention given to vectors with subscripts

I can't find any equivalent in ConTeXt. I've found [this conversation](https://mailman.ntg.nl/pipermail/ntg-context/2016/085828.html), but the result doesn't suit me, especially with the subscript case.
I tried to use directly esvect's code, but it seems to use LaTeX programming utilities (so it is not Plain TeX, and not usable as-is in ConTeXt). I've tried adapting it (the package is about 20 lines of code, so I thought it would be feasible), but since I'm not a TeX programmer at all, I quickly abandoned.

Is there a Plain TeX programmer who would be able to make such a small translation ? Or any other satisfying alternative ?

### EDIT

I understand that I poorly asked the question : my aim is to use the features of the esvect package with ConTeXt. I asked for a Plain TeX version because I (wrongly, as Henri Menke explained in the comments) thought it was usable as-is with ConTeXt, and that it might be easier to produce or reach more programmers. Henri Menke provided a perfectly working Plain TeX version, but since it isn't usable with ConTeXt, it is not what I seeked in the end. Is it possible to have a ConTeXt version of this package ? Since I am neither a TeX programmer nor a metapost user, I don't know what should be the best way to handle it...
Thanks in advance.

### SECOND EDIT

Since @Aditya asked me to explain my problem in a more clear way, I made a comparison (with the Palatino font, since it is the one I use) of what I can acheive with esvect, what is with done basically by LaTeX and by ConTeXt. Below are the codes, then the snapshots, then the details :

```
%% LaTeX code
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo}
\linespread{1.05}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[g]{esvect}
\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
  esvect package
  \begin{equation*}
    \vv{F}_{\text{spring}\to M} = -k(x-\ell_{0})\vv*{u}{x}
  \end{equation*}
  \begin{equation*}
    \text{correct } \vv{AB}, \vv{\imath}
  \end{equation*}
  \begin{equation*}
    \vv*{u}{x} \text{ more adapted than } \vv{u}_{x}
  \end{equation*}
  \begin{equation*}
    \vv{v} = -\vv{grad}\phi
  \end{equation*}

  out of the box
  \begin{equation*}
    \vec{F}_{\text{spring}\to M} = -k(x-\ell_{0})\vec{u}_{x}
  \end{equation*}
  \begin{equation*}
    \text{awful }\vec{AB}, \text{ correct } \vec{\imath}
  \end{equation*}
  \begin{equation*}
    \vv*{u}{x} \text{ better arrow, worse spacing than } \vec{u}_{x}
  \end{equation*}
  \begin{equation*}
    \vec{v} = -\vec{grad}\phi
  \end{equation*}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}

% ConTeXt code
\usemodule[simplefonts]
\definefontfeature[default][default][onum=yes]
\setupbodyfont[11pt,palatino]

\starttext
\startformula
  \vec{F}_{\text{spring}\to M} = -k(x-\ell_{0})\vec{u}_{x}
\stopformula
\startformula
  \text{correct } \vec{AB}, \vec{\imath}
\stopformula
\startformula
  \text{neither } \vec{u}_{x} \text{ nor } \vec{u_{x}}
\stopformula
\startformula
  \vec{v} = -\vec{grad}\phi
\stopformula
\stoptext
```

Below is the result with LaTeX:
[image]

And below is the result with ConTeXT
[image]

Finally, what I seek in esvect can be summarized as this :

- On one-letter vectors, the arrow is a bit longer on both sides, and I find it much more readable
- On vectors with subscripts, it still makes arrows a bit longer, but also correct the spacing, so that the subscript is already under the arrow tip (I think the correction could be a bit stronger though, but I'm not thinking that this level of detail is important now)
- On multi-letters vectors, it behaves naturally as `\overrightarrow`, which ConTeXt does out of the box
- Some special cases such as the grad or `ìmath` are not perfect but acceptable in my opinion
- I prefer esvect's arrow look, but palatino's is fine by me

Maybe I could use TikZ to create my vector commands, but even if I have experience of TikZ I never did this kind of programming (I only drawed pre-defined plots).

Comment: The `esvect` macro package provides a math font and defines macros that use symbols from that font. To use this in ConTeXt, you will need to define a virtual font where the `esvect` arrows are stylistic variants. There are some examples of virtual fonts in `tex/context/fonts/...` subdirectory, but they are for "standard" math fonts. I don't know enough about Opentype Math fonts to create mappings for new symbols.

Comment: The question of the arrow type is only marginal to me ; the style obtained with the default \vec command is not perfect, but fine by me. My real problem the problem of subscripted vectors, and I suppose (I may be wrong) that the macros don't depend on the arrow style.

Comment: What do you mean by "problem of subscripted vectors"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally used TiKZ to make my vector arrows and reached a result that suits me. This is not perfect but covers most of my usage cases - and I can add specific new cases when needed, now that I have understood the principle. The main problem is the management of superscripts, as @Aditya pointed out : it is neither natural (having a different command is not straightforward) nor perfect (I did not test many letters, and the results seems to depend on the immediate environment when the basic `\vv` command is used).

However, I wonder if it wouldn't be more ConTeXt-ish to use metapost instead of TikZ, and define these vector arrows as proper mathstackers / accents. My methods somehow feels like a tinkerer thing, more along the lines of Plain TeX philosophy than ConTeXt's (as far as I understand). I would prefer accepting an answer more along ConTeXt's usage that my own TikZ thing - and I would probably learn some more along the way !

```
\usemodule[simplefonts]
\definefontfeature[default][default][onum=yes]
\setupbodyfont[11pt,palatino,ss]
\usemodule[tikz]
\usetikzlibrary[arrows.meta]
\usetikzlibrary[calc]
\setuppapersize[A5][A5]

% Other stuff
\def\doDdiff[#1][#2]{  % différentielles et dérivées secondes - macro interne
  \ifsecondargument {\frac{{\rm d^2} #1}{{\rm d} {#2}^2}}
  \else {\rm d^2} \fi
}
\def\ddiff{\dodoubleempty\doDdiff} 

% Vectors
\def\doVV[#1][#2]{  
  \ifsecondargument {\vvtwo{#1}{#2}} \else {\vvone{#1}} \fi
}
\def\vv{\dodoubleempty\doVV} 

\def\vvone#1{
    \tikz[baseline=(char.base),
      -> /.tip = {Straight Barb[length=0.2em,width=0.5ex,slant=0.3]}]{
      \def\vup{0.3ex}
      \node[inner sep=0pt] (char) {$#1$};
      \draw[->] ($(char.north west)+(0,\vup)$) -- ($(char.north
      east)+(0.1em,\vup)$);
    }
}
\def\vvtwo#1#2{
  \tikz[baseline=(char.base),
    -> /.tip = {Straight Barb[length=0.2em,width=0.5ex,slant=0.3]}]{
    \def\vup{0.3ex}
    \node[inner sep=0pt, text opacity=0] (char) {$#1$};
    \node[inner sep=0pt, anchor=base west] (full) at (char.base west) {$#1_{#2}$};
    \draw[->] ($(char.north west)+(0,\vup)$) -- ($(char.north
    east)+(0.1em,\vup)$);
  }
}
\def\vsuper[#1][#2]{
  \tikz[baseline=(char.base),
    -> /.tip = {Straight Barb[length=0.2em,width=0.5ex,slant=0.3]}]{
    \def\vup{0.3ex}
    \node[inner sep=0pt, text opacity=0] (char) {$#1$};
    \node[inner sep=0pt, anchor=base west] (full) at (char.base west) {$#1^{#2}$};
    \draw[->] ($(char.north west)+(0,\vup)$) -- ($(char.north
    east)+(-0.em,\vup)$);
  }
}

\starttext

\startcolumns[2,rule=on]
  My version
  \startformula
    \vv[F]_{\text{spring}\to M} = -k(x-\ell_{0})\vv[u][x]
  \stopformula
  \startformula
    m \ddiff[{\vv[r]}][t] = \vv[F] + m\vv[g] + \vv[R]
  \stopformula
  \startformula
    \vv[AB], \vv[\imath]
  \stopformula
  \startformula
    \vv[u][x], \vv[u][y], \vv[u][z], \vv[u][X], \vv[u][Y], \vv[u][Z], \vv[u][X_{1}],
    \vv[u][x_{1}]
  \stopformula
  \startformula
    \vv[L][\Delta], \vv[J][\Delta], \vv[J][xx], \vv[u][x]
  \stopformula
  \startformula
    \vsuper[v][2] \text{ means } \vv[v]\cdot\vv[v]
  \stopformula
  \startformula
    \vv[v]',\vv[v']\text{ no } , \vv[v]' \text{ strangely works}
  \stopformula
  \startformula
    \vsuper[v][\prime],\vsuper[v][\prime 2] \text{ ok}
  \stopformula
  \column

  Out of the box vec
  \startformula
    \vec{F}_{\text{spring}\to M} = -k(x-\ell_{0})\vec{u}_{x}
  \stopformula
  \startformula
    m \ddiff[\vec{r}][t] = \vec{F} + m\vec{g} + \vec{R}
  \stopformula
  \startformula
    \vec{AB}, \vec{\imath}
  \stopformula
  \startformula
    \vec{u}_{x}, \vec{u}_{y}, \vec{u}_{z}, \vec{u}_{X}, \vec{u}_{Y}, \vec{u}_{Z},     \vec{u}_{X_{1}},  \vec{u}_{x_{1}}
  \stopformula
  \startformula
    \vec{L}_{\Delta}, \vec{J}_{\Delta}, \vec{J}_{xx}, \vec{u}_{x}
  \stopformula
  \startformula
    \vec{v}^{2}  \text{ means } \vec{v}\cdot\vec{v}
  \stopformula
  \startformula
    \vec{v}'
  \stopformula
\stopcolumns
\stoptext
```

[image]

Comment: What about when you also want to use superscripts? Is the output that you get with your solution the desired one?

Comment: I didn't think about this case. There is only one case where I guess I could use it, for the norm of the vector `\vv[v]^2` ; in this case the ouput is really bad. I will try to adapt to this case as well and edit this answer.

Comment: I edited my answer with the superscript question, it is indeed more complicated that what I thougth.

Comment: While searching for a Metapost solution, I've found these two packages which permit changing the arrow heads : https://www.ctan.org/pkg/mparrows and http://tlcontrib.metatex.org/cgi-bin/package.cgi/action=view/id=791. I was wondering how I could try them in my standalone distribution.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to convert `esvect` to Plain TeX.  However, I couldn't get it to work in ConTeXt.

```
\catcode`@=11

% load fonts
\font\tenvec=vect10 at 10pt
\font\sevenvec=vect7 at 7pt
\font\fivevec=vect5 at 5pt

%% define new family
\newfam\vecfam
\textfont\vecfam=\tenvec
\scriptfont\vecfam=\sevenvec
\scriptscriptfont\vecfam=\fivevec

%% convert count register to hex
\def\thehex#1{\ifcase#1 0\or 1\or 2\or 3\or 4\or 5\or 6\or 7\or 8\or 9\or
  A\or B\or C\or D\or E\or F\fi}

%% define symbols
\mathchardef\fldr="3\thehex\vecfam 12 % adjust here to select another arrow
\mathchardef\montraita="3\thehex\vecfam 20
\mathchardef\montraitd="3\thehex\vecfam 23

%% copied from esvect.sty (with little adjustments)
\def\relbareda{\mathrel{\mathpalette\mathsm@sh\montraita}}
\def\relbaredd{\mathrel{\mathpalette\mathsm@sh\montraitd}}
\def\vv{\futurelet\ifstar\dovv}
\def\dovv{\ifx*\ifstar\expandafter\vvstar\else\expandafter\ESV@vecteur\fi}
\def\vvstar*#1#2{\ESV@vecteur{#1}_{\mkern-1mu\relax#2}}
\def\ESV@vecteur{\mathpalette{\overvect@\vectfill@}}
\def\vectfill@{\traitfill@\relbaredd\relbareda\fldr}
\def\traitfill@#1#2#3#4{%
  $\m@th\mkern2mu\relax#4#1\mkern-1.5mu%on met \relbaredd au d\'ebut
   \cleaders\hbox{$#4\mkern0mu#2\mkern0mu$}\hfill%remplit avec relbareda
   \mkern-1.5mu#3$%
}
\def\overvect@#1#2#3{\vbox{\ialign{##\crcr%
 \noalign{\kern-.7pt\nointerlineskip}#1#2\crcr%
 \noalign{\kern-.3pt\nointerlineskip}$\m@th\hfil#2#3\hfil$\crcr}}}

%% We'd need these from plain.tex if we would run in ConTeXt
%\def\m@th{\mathsurround\zeropoint}
%\def\mathsm@sh#1#2{\setbox\z@\hbox{$\m@th #1{#2}$}\finsm@sh}
%\def\finsm@sh{\ht\z@\z@ \dp\z@\z@ \box\z@}

\catcode`@=12

%% Test:

Some examples from the manual:

$\vv{E}$, $\vv{AB}$, $\vv{\imath}$ and $\vv{u}$

$\vv*{e}{r}$ and $\vv*{L}{\Delta}$

$\vv{E}_{\vv{u}_{\vv{u}}}$

\bye
```

[image]

Comment: It is probably because I don't understand anything about the Plain TeX / ConTeXt interface, but I  thought Plain TeX code was directly usable in ConteXt or LaTeX.

Comment: @A.Licari Well, ConTeXt inherently uses Unicode math fonts and all of its math mode setup is tailored towards this.  This includes overloading primitves and adjusting font loading.  If `esvect` were available as a Unicode math font you'd surely stand better chances.